# Android load imageView with drawable depending on data received from firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase, imageview, drawable

I cant find a way to set image to imageView from drawable folder depending on string data received from Firebase Database.

I get values from Firebase Database like this:

```
    DatabaseReference personsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Persons");
    Query personsQuery = personsRef.orderByKey();
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions personsOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Adapter>().setQuery(personsQuery, Adapter.class).build();
    
             mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Adapter, Tab1.MyViewHolder>(personsOptions) {
                            @Override
                            protected void onBindViewHolder(Tab1.MyViewHolder holder, final int position, final Adapter model) {
                
                                holder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                                holder.setDate(model.getDate());
        }

            @Override
            public Tab1.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycle_tab1, parent, false);
                return new Tab1.MyViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
```

The goal is to populate imageViews in RecyclerView with images from drawable folder depending on data loaded from Firebase. Something like: if "title" loaded from firebase = 1, set imageView to R.drawable.thisPerson1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append your received string to ImageView Resource ID

```
DatabaseReference personsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Persons");
Query personsQuery = personsRef.orderByKey();
FirebaseRecyclerOptions personsOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Adapter>().setQuery(personsQuery, Adapter.class).build();

         mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Adapter, Tab1.MyViewHolder>(personsOptions) {
                        @Override
                        protected void onBindViewHolder(Tab1.MyViewHolder holder, final int position, final Adapter model) {
            
                            holder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                            holder.setDate(model.getDate());
                            holder.yourImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable+"."+model.getImage())
    }

        @Override
        public Tab1.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycle_tab1, parent, false);
            return new Tab1.MyViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the fastest solution for the problem.
holder.yourImageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier((model.getImage()),"drawable", getActivity().getPackageName()));

Answer (score 0):

If title is number like 0..10 then u could try to create res array:

if 1..10 then try to use `model.getTitle() - 1` etc.

```xml
<integer-array name="some_name">
    <item>@drawable/thisPerson1</item>
    <item>@drawable/thisPerson2</item>
    <item>@drawable/thisPerson3</item>
    <item>@drawable/thisPerson4</item>
</integer-array>
```

```java
private TypedArray imagesArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.some_name);
private int image = imagesArray.getResourceId(imagesArray.getIndex(title), defaultValue)

ImageView.setBackgroundResource(image)

imagesArray.recycle()
```